# Is there any real world application of indirect addressing in some software using programming language like C?

Tags: c, pointers

I was watching [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rxvv9krECNw&t=20m21s) and this guy tells about indirect addressing using pointers. He says that an address can be passed through the function call in main function which can be collected at the function definition by pointer variables. So that we can change the value of variable that are  inside  main function. How is this useful in real case scenarios? Doesn't this be misused if some one uses this for programming in real case software building. Please enlighten me. Can anyone please give me an example of real world example where indirect addressing is used in software architecture?

```
main()
{
    int var1;
    function1(int &var1)
}
void function1(int *var1){
    *var1=*var1+1;
}
```

Comment: at what time moment did you see it ?

Comment: i am watching it now

Comment: ***facepalm*** No... at what portion of the video did you see the reference?

Comment: around 30 min 21 sec

Comment: @sobha then **please link to that part**

Comment: If your question is, why pass an address to a function: assume that you have a struct which is quite big, say 1MB. If you would pass the object itself, when it creates the stack frame, it has to allocate enough memory to fit your 1MB object. Whereas, passing a pointer it's just--usually-- 1 word. Not to mention that any changes to that object would be lost, since the stack pointer gets decremented and the struct is gone.

Comment: @Antti Haapala it starts from 20 min

Comment: There is no way to write a non-trivial useful C program without indirect addressing. `printf("Hello world");` - guess what, you're using indirect addressing there already! Perhaps a program like `/bin/true` or `/bin/false` can be considered *useful*, and it does not need to use indirect addressing, just a main that returns `1` or `0'.

Comment: @Vio Ariton. Thank you.That make a lot of sense.But can you add to that where this is used in some live projects

Comment: @sobha All the C projects use pointers. That's the core essence of C: pointers. For instance, when you dynamically allocate memory using malloc, it returns you a pointer to the address and when you want to deallocate the object, you pass the address to the deallocation function.

Comment: I think it's a little strong to say that pointers are "the core essence" of C, but they certainly are of enormous importance.  And it is true that every signle C program of any interest uses pointers.  The same is true of most other popular programming languages, though few expose that fact as clearly or accessibly as C does.

Answer (score 3):

> How is this useful in real case scenarios.

Well, even the most basic "hello world" input example needs to have another function (in this case `scanf()`) be able to modify a variable inside `main()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char input;
    printf("Enter a single character: ");
    scanf("%c", &input);
    printf("You entered: %c\n", input);
    return 0;
}
```

If you couldn't pass the address of `input` to `scanf()`, then it wouldn't be able to modify it.

Pointers are needed because the evaluation strategy of the C language is "call by value" (also known as "pass by value".) This means that when calling a function, all parameters that are passed are evaluated **before** the function call occurs. The effect of this is that the called function has no access to the variable that is being passed to it. It only has access the value of that variable.

Very often this is fine. Not all functions need to have access to the variable that is being passed. `printf()` for example doesn't need access to `input`, it only needs the value of `input`.

But a function like `scanf()` on the other hand is not interested in the value of `input`. It needs to somehow access the variable itself. To achieve that, a pointer needs to be passed, which evaluates to an address. The called function receives that address and thus has access to whatever variable is stored at that address.

> Doesn't this be misused if some one uses this for programming in real case software building.

Yes. Mistakes in handling pointers are among the most popular sources of software bugs. There are other languages out there with a strong focus on avoiding pointers as a means to eliminate pointer-related software defects.

Answer (score 2):

A classic example is designing a singly-linked list (or any other kind of list) and writing a function that pushes nodes to the list.

For example

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

int push_front( struct Node **head, int data )
{
    struct Node *tmp = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
    int success = tmp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        tmp->data = data;
        tmp->next = *head;
        *head = tmp;
    }

    return success;
}    


int main( void )
{
    struct Node *head;

    for ( int i = 0; i != 10; i++ ) push_front( &head, i );

    //...
}
```

So as you can see the function `push_front` accepts `head` by reference and thus changes the original value of `head`. As result `head` in `main` will always point to the newly added node.

So it is a usual practise passing data by reference to a function if the function needs to change the original value of data.

And a more largely used concept of passing data by reference is processing arrays that is not evident for beginners.

For example let's consider the function

```
void fill_array( int a[], size_t n, int value )
{
    for ( int *p = a; p != a + n; p++ ) *p = value;
}
```

It fills an array with a value.

In fact, each element of the array is passed to the function through a pointer.:)

The function declaration is adjusted by the compiler the following way

```
void fill_array( int *a, size_t n, int value );
```

And when you pass to the function an array like for example this

```
enum { N = 10 };
int a[N];

fill_array( a, N, 10 );
```

then the array designator is implicitly converted to pointer to the first element of the array. That is this call is equivalent to the following call

```
fill_array( &a[0], N, 10 );
```

So using this pointer you in fact passes all elements of the array indirectly (by reference) through this pointer. And the loop in the function demonstrates this

```
    for ( int *p = a, p != a + n; p++ ) *p = value;
```

Each value of the pointer `p` points to an original element of the array and changes its calue.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fill_array( int a[], size_t n, int value )
{
    for ( int *p = a; p != a + n; p++ ) *p = value;
}

// This declaration is redundant 
// but shows how the compiler adjusts a parameter of an array type
void fill_array( int *a, size_t n, int value );

int main( void )
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    int a[N];

    fill_array( a, N, 10 );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

Its output is

```
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any real world application of indirect addressing in some software using programming language like c?

Yes. Virtually ALL C programs uses pointers.

> How is this useful in real case scenarios?

For starters, there is no other way to pass an array to a function in C. So as soon as you want to pass an array you need pointers. Also, a function cannot return an array. You have to use pointers there too.

Another reason is if you want to modify the arguments, and this is common. This is especially useful when you don't want the function to handle the memory allocation.

Actually, in C, it does exist two different functions that does the same thing: `strcpy` and `strdup`. Well, the latter one does not belong to the standard but it's fairly common. They both copy a string. Here is an example of how to use them:

```
int main(void) 
{
    char *str = "Hello, World!";

    // When using strcpy, we need to allocate the memory first
    char *copy1 = malloc(strlen(str)+1);
    strcpy(copy1, str);

    // We don't need to do that with strdup
    char *copy2 = strdup(str);

    // But we still need to free the allocated memory for both
    free(copy1);
    free(copy2);
}
```

`strcpy` writes to one of its arguments, while `strdup` returns a pointer to the memory it has allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Indirection is a powerful technique in programming, whether it’s done through pointers or not.  Array indexing is a form of indirection, as are functions writing to their input parameters.

A number of sophisticated data structures such as lists, trees, queues, etc. use indirection extensively.

C and C++ are rare in that they expose pointer *types* and operations on those types directly to the programmer.  Most other languages hide those kinds of operations so that you the programmer are not generally aware of it.

C *requires* us to use pointers in 2 cases:

1. To write to a function’s parameter:

   ```
   void foo( T *ptr ) // for any type T
   {
     *ptr = some_value(); // write a new value to the thing ptr points to
   }

   void bar( void )
   {
     T var;

     foo( &var ); // write a new value to var
   }
   ```

   To track dynamically allocated memory:

   ```
   T *mem = malloc( sizeof *mem * num_elements );
   ```

Pointers can also be used to implement a number of dynamic data structures like lists, trees, queues, etc.  A typical list type looks like

```
struct listnode
{
  T data; // for any type T
  struct listnode *next;
};
```

Each entry in the list explicitly points to the next entry.  Adding a new entry in the middle of the list is just a matter of shuffling pointers:

```
+––––––+––––––+               +––––––+––––––+
| data | next | ––––––––––––> | data | next |
+––––––+––––––+               +––––––+––––––+

               +––––––+––––––+
               | data | next |
               +––––––+––––––+


+––––––+––––––+               +––––––+––––––+
| data | next |               | data | next |
+––––––+––––––+               +––––––+––––––+
           |                     ^
           |   +––––––+––––––+   |
           +–> | data | next |–––+
               +––––––+––––––+
```

In code, that would look something like:

```
new_node->next = cur->next;
cur->next = new_node;
```

Compare that with trying to insert a new element n the middle of an array - you’d have to shuffle all the elements that would follow the new entry one element down first.

Now, you don’t *have* to use pointers to perform indirection - as I mentioned, array indexing is a form of indirection.  When I took data structures in college, we used Fortran 77, which did not have any kind of pointer types.  We implemented everything using arrays, and array indices were our “pointers”.

Answer (score 0):

a very simple example. shift the string left:

```
char *shift(char *str) 
{
  char *svd = str;
  while(*str)
  {
    *str = *(str + 1);
    str++;
  }
  return str;
}
```