# Uneven allocation of memory for this stack program

Tags: c, pointers

I have a small program got from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56304892/is-there-any-real-world-application-of-indirect-addressing-in-some-software-usin) which pushes element into the stack.On careful examination I see that the storage space taken by this next pointer in the program for the first value ,second value,and third value is different.Can anyone please give me a satisfactory explanation for  why it is happening like this.
I am using gcc compiler

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

int push_front( struct Node **head, int data )
{
    struct Node *tmp = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
    int success = tmp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    { 
        tmp->data = data;
        tmp->next = *head;
        *head = tmp;
         printf("\nAddress of pointer head now is %p for value %d",*head,data);
    }

    return success;
}    



int main( void )
{
    struct Node *head;

    for ( int i = 0; i != 10; i++ ) push_front( &head, i );

return 0;


}

=======================================================================
output
-----

Address of pointer head now is 0x16f1010 for value 0
Address of pointer head now is 0x16f1440 for value 1
Address of pointer head now is 0x16f1460 for value 2
Address of pointer head now is 0x16f1480 for value 3
Address of pointer head now is 0x16f14a0 for value 4
Address of pointer head now is 0x16f14c0 for value 5
Address of pointer head now is 0x16f14e0 for value 6
Address of pointer head now is 0x16f1500 for value 7
Address of pointer head now is 0x16f1520 for value 8
Address of pointer head now is 0x16f1540 for value 9
```

The expectation is such that the header pointer should take equal bytes of address space while inserting each value.

Comment: Undefined behavior for using the value of an object with automatic storage duration while it is indeterminate.

Comment: It's going by the assumption that the memory will be allocated one directly after the other which isn't the case.

Comment: You assume that successive `malloc()` will allocate contiguous memory. This has no reason to happen. Malloc() tries to optimize memory use and to respect page boundaries, alignment constraints, etc. So no reason to have contiguous memory. BTW why do you assume they are allocated on the stack? Only local variables are in your program. malloc allocates in the heap.

Comment: @Alain Merigot  .I thought that the memory will contiguous.Thanks for answering this and providing me with this new fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`malloc` is used to dynamically allocate a **contiguous block** of memory of a given size. This memory is allocated from the heap.

`malloc` makes no guarantees that the memory allocated between two subsequent calls to `malloc` be **contiguous**.